# Unity Визуализация для дебага

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как что либо отобразить на сцене, наподобие того, что когда пытаешься изменить форму коллайдера, его форма отображается в редакторе? [image: Как рисовать такие же зеленые линии?]

Comment: [Handles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.html) (еще символы)